# Can Firebase work on a Servlet?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, servlets, firebase-admin

I am trying to use **Firebase** Admin on a Servlet that is communicating on App Engine (Google Cloud Platform). I am using a Servlet because I need to generate a Token towards to validate my access to another API that I am using.

Did anyone have this successful history using Firebase on a Servlet?

I am using `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.2.0`

App Engine **SDK**

```
com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.50
com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.54
```

Inside the **GET** I am taking the Token to access the Merchant API.

```
    String mToken = gateway.clientToken().generate();

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("nonce", mToken);
    resp.getWriter().println(jsonObject.toString());
```

Inside the **POST Firebase Admin** Full Privileges.

All firebase is inside of a single try and the Transaction Request is in another try.

```
 FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("/WEB-INF/...json");
 FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
         .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
         .setDatabaseUrl("https://MyProject.firebaseio.com/")
         .build();

 FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

**IAM already grant the read permission.**

**Firebase Database Reference with the Transaction**

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference("price");


ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String res = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
try {
        TransactionRequest request = new TransactionRequest()

                .amount(new BigDecimal(res)) //Res doesn't show any error but it also doesn't work
                .paymentMethodNonce(nonce)
                .options()
                .submitForSettlement(true)
                .storeInVaultOnSuccess(true)
                .done();


        Result<Transaction> result = gateway.transaction().sale(request);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Im dealing with the same thing!

Comment: are you looking for this https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio#writing_the_servlet_code

Comment: can you please tell exactly what you are trying to do? I am using Firebase Admin on Google App Engine. So what is your problem?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer I have edited. I am trying to use the value price (res) and use it on the amount of the Transaction Request, it doesn't show any code error. Firebase and Transaction are Asynchronous Threads.

Comment: @Krutik, yes but I am not doing the email, I am retrieving a value and trying to use it on the Transaction Request.

Comment: @Andrea Are you using also Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Java Admin SDK often gets used inside servlets. You will need to use a [manually scaled](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/an-overview-of-app-engine#scaling_types_and_instance_classes) instance to deploy on App Engine. Firebase database client starts long running threads, and hence cannot operate on the auto-scaled instances (the new GAE java8 runtime seems more lenient in this regard, but I cannot confirm that right now).

I would recommend you to call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()` only once per app, ideally inside a [`ServletContextListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). Then in your servlet, you should be able to perform your transaction as you do now.